sqlplus does not use column separators for specific output
i am trying to build an sql plus script that extracts some values out of my database to do a log search with them afterwards. It looks like this, amended to not use real data:
IFS='' read -r -d '' SQL <<EOF
SET heading off
set colsep ';'
set trimspool on
set newpage none
set feedback off
set linesize 500
set numwidth 20
alter session set nls_date_format = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS';
SELECT T1.FIELD1, 
REGEXP_SUBSTR(T2.FIELD2, '<Tag>[^\<]*'),
T2.FIELD3
FROM TABLE1 T1
LEFT JOIN TABLE2 T2 ON T2.LINK = T1.LINK
WHERE
T1.PARTITION_KEY BETWEEN ($P_PARTITION_KEY -3) and $P_PARTITION_KEY 
AND T2.PARTITION_KEY BETWEEN ($P_PARTITION_KEY -3) and $P_PARTITION_KEY
    AND T1.FIELD4 = ${FIELD4};
EOF

    for line in "$(echo "${SQL}" | sqlplus -S $(getdbcon client) | sed -e "s/[[:space:]]//g")"
    do
            for singleline in `IFS='\n' echo "${line}"`; do
                    IFS=';' read -r FIELD1 FIELD2 FIELD3 <<< "$singleline"
            done
    done
    echo $SQL  
    echo  $FIELD1 $FIELD2 $FIELD3
    test="$(echo "${SQL}" | sqlplus -S $(getdbcon client)| sed -e "s/[[:space:]]//g" )"
    echo "$test"

This gives out:
FIELD3 blank blank
FIELD1
FIELD2
FIELD3

I would expect though that it returns
FIELD1 FIELD2 FIELD3
FIELD1;FIELD2;FIELD3

The content of the fields are as expected, but, for some reason, sqlplus has not returned these fields with ; as separator. If i omit FIELD2 that was build using REGEXP_SUBSTR, it does work. With every other query, i am reusing this quite a bit, it works.
The field is just the content of a big NVARCHAR2(4000 CHAR) field that is holding an xml. The same script worked on a different row of the same table, where i used a NCLOB column. For this one however i needed to use the other field and suddenly the same does not work anymore. I am not exactly sure what is causing this, it cannot be the specifics of regexp_substr as this one was already successful.
Fixed: Not sure why sqlplus did not want to do like i wanted, but it fixed it by converting FIELD2 to NCLOB in the query:
REGEXP_SUBSTR(T2.FIELD2, '[^<]'), ->>> TO_NCLOB(REGEXP_SUBSTR(T2.FIELD2, '[^<]')),

Can't immediately replicate. Sample data might help but it seems to be behaving; perhaps your XML has semicolons in it, or control characters, or something. Run the SQL manually in SQL*Plus and see what you get. Also why are you using regex to get values out of an XML document (and keeping the tag name), rather than the built-in XML functions? Stripping whitespace also looks wrong, and maybe consider using SQLcl instead of SQL*Plus to generate delimited output.

I am actually just a script kiddie trying to build something that helps me at my job, building upon stuff that once worked for me, sometimes without really understanding it :) My workaround for the issue so far is to create a second query that only gets the problematic FIELD2, and have FIELD1 and FIELD3 be grabbed by the above query. This works, using a simple DIELD2="$(echo "${SQL}" | sqlplus -S $(getdbcon 1900) | sed -e "s/[[:space:]]//g")" gets the content, which is alpha numeric if i want to. So it cannot be the content of the tag.
